# How to remove lines in extra unused space in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

[image]

I created a DataGrid shown in the image above, which has extra unused space in the right part.
Could you tell me how it is possible to remove lines in the unused space?

CAUTION: In my case, the extra unused space MUST exist in the right part. I'd like to remove lines alone.

**SOLUTION:**

I resolved my question by setting `GridLinesVisibility="NONE"` and setting a template for a DataGridCell as shown in the code below. Thank you very much for your help, everyone.

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0, 0, 0.5, 0.5"
                        Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background}">
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `GridLinesVisibility="Vertical"` on the datagrid, and then override the cellstyle:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

which will set the border on each cell to only the bottom border, and each column will have vertical grid lines displayed only.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I resolved my question by setting a template for a DataGridCell.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove extra rows by using CanUserAddRows property. Also you can remove extra created column by using AutoGenerateColumns property.

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
.................
</DataGrid>
```